# Should I encode curly or square brackets inside a JSON?

Tags: mysql, json

In fact, the title says it all. But, I'll go more into details:

I am sending a JSON string from my JS script to the server and vice versa. The JSON contains things as some content the user wrote into a textfield, but I know that some user will manage to break the JSON array this way sooner or later, so I decided to encode it with `encodeURIComponent()`.

But I see, that when I try to encode curly brackets, that they aren't encoded at all. Is this going to be a problem?

[image: Encoding of some characters]

More precisely, I'm afraid that if someone writes: `} , {`, the JSON will break. This shouldn't happen, since all of it is inside doublequotes like this: `"} , {"`, and if a user write doublequotes or singlequotes they are going to be encoded, and from what I know, JSON should handle all of that just fine, but I am not entirely sure.

So, should I encode those brackets?

(Another thing is that the data is inserted into MySQL inside prepared statements, so that shouldn't be a problem, or I am wrong with that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick quote from the [JSON specifications](http://www.json.org):

> A *string* is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

As you can see in the image that follows the paragraph quoted above, any Unicode character except for `"`, `\` and control characters is represented as-is; no escape is required.

Answer (score 2):

why will brake? Your JSON string will be inside `""`

So will be something like

```
{"postcontent": "Shouldnt { } be escaped"}
```

Comment: It seems that in this case I am correct with my hipothesis I just wrote...

Comment: Yes, the only problem could came from single and double quotes, but you say are encoding those ;)

Comment: Single quotes are not special characters in JSON. They do not need any encoding or escaping.